# How to activate my Stellar Account?

Tags: transactions, accounts

[image: Please, help me to activate my account]

We have been fighting for weeks and our broker can not deposit any XLM because our account is not activated. Please, let me know how to activate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you need to fund above account and that need to be account that's not from CEX.IO.

You may buy from other and send it's to your account once your account funded it's will activate automatic.

Hope it's help